# Gradle: compile vs compileOnly

Tags: java, gradle

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
}
```

в итоге получу jar-ку, которая не будет содержать бинарники log4j.
Тогда какая разница между compile и compileOnly, если в итоге получится одна и та же jar-ка?

Answer (score 3):

Идеологически `compile` и `compileOnly` различаются тем, что `compile` зависимости следует распространять вместе с приложением, а `compileOnly` либо не нужны во время выполнения (например, библиотеки с аннотациями использующимися только во время компиляции), либо предоставляются средой выполнения (например, Java EE контейнер должен предоставляь свою реализацию JPA или Servlet).

В вашем конкретном случае вы просто не там ищете бинарники log4j, они будут в `build/distributions/${project.name}.zip/${project.name}/lib`. Плагин `application` пакует зависимости не в JAR, а в этот архив. При этом пакуются только `compile` зависимости, а `compileOnly` - нет.

Если вы хотите паковать зависимости в JAR, то вы можете этого добиться при помощи плагина [FatJar](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin) или такой конфигурации таска `jar`:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "root.package.of.my.Application"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```